# Design a data structure that supports build(s), insert(S,k), delete_max (S), delete_old(S,t) and add_to_new (S,d) in constant time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm doing an algorithm course and I'm stuck on a question.

I need to suggest a data structure that supports the following:

build(S): build the structure S with n values in O(n*lgn)

insert(S,k): insert the value k into S in O(lgn)

delete_max(S): delete the max value from S in O(lgn)

delete_old(S,t): delete the t oldest value from S in o(lng)

add_to_new(S,d): add value d to the last value that entered to S in O(Lng)

We just learned Red-Black Trees so I think I probably need to use this structure and add something to it, or to add another structure that will help me with delete_old(S,t).
I'm struggling to understand how to update the "age" of each value after I use the "delete_old(S,t)".

Lets say that I entered to S: 11,22,44,68,79... Then 11 is the oldest, 22 is the second oldest, etc.
After I deleted the 3rd oldest (value 44), now 68 need to become the 3rd oldest and 79 will be the 4th oldest, etc- how would I update the ages of all the remaining values after the one I deleted in O(lng)?

I hope my question is clear. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To support two orderings, you need to mix two ordered data structures.

For example, you can create a node for each value, and link it into two separate red-black trees, one ordered by value and one ordered by age.  Of course the node object would need two sets of links and two `isRed` fields.

If you want to leverage the libraries that your language already provides, then you can make a node object that just has a value and age in it, and insert it into two separate trees.

Comment: But then for deleting the t oldest, I need to walk on the list t steps, isn't it going to cause it to be more than O(lng)? if we want to delete the oldest we need to go over all the list and then it will be O(n)+ O(lng)= O(n) no?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted to delete the oldest.  I'll adjust this.

Comment: Ok, thank you! but I still have the same issue, once you want to take the 6th oldest from the tree- how would you update the 7th, 8th etc to be the 6th and the 7th in O(lgn)?

Comment: You need to add a measure of its subtree size (in the age tree) to each node: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree